# Vue: vue-i18n: Cannot translate the value of keypath, Use the value of keypath as default

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-i18n

I am using Vue, and I want to show three languages. English, Tagalog and Cebuano.

Now I have the error:

> Cannot translate the value of keypath 'NavbarMobile.home'. Use the
> value of keypath as default.

I checked if the plugin is working by console.log(this.$i18n.locale).
And the result was "en".
"en" is my default language, English.

Is this issue is coming from my configuration?

NavbarMobile.js

```js
<b-list-group-item
  :to="{name:'Home'}"
  active
  class="flex-column align-items-start home-item"
>
  <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
    <!-- Home -->
    {{ $t('NavbarMobile.home') }}
  </div>
 </b-list-group-item>
```

main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import i18n from './lang/lang';
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

lang.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import english from './en.js'
import tagalog from './tg.js'
import cebuano from './ce.js'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  lazy: true,
  locale: "en",
  "en" : english,
  "tg" : tagalog,
  "ce" : cebuano,
});

export default {
  i18n
}
```

en.js

```js
const english = {
  "en": {
    "NavbarMobile": {
      "home": "Home",
      "pro": "Pro version",
      "contact": "Contact",
      "help": "Help",
      "profile": "Profile",
      "login": "Login",
      "logout": "Logout",
      "terms and conditions": "Terms and conditions",
      "follow us": "Follow us"
      },
    }
  }

export default {
  english
}
```

I have JavaScript files for Tagalog and Cebuano languages in the same format.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You are using `VueI18n` incorrectly, translations need to be passed into `messages` property
2. Object passed into `messages` property need to have locale codes at 1st level only, now you have it twice (in constructor and in `en.js`)

```js
const i18n = new VueI18n({
  lazy: true,
  locale: "en",
  messages: {
    "en" : english,
    "tg" : tagalog,
    "ce" : cebuano,
  },
});
```

`en.js`

```js
export default {
  "NavbarMobile": {
    "home": "Home",
    "pro": "Pro version",
    "contact": "Contact",
    "help": "Help",
    "profile": "Profile",
    "login": "Login",
    "logout": "Logout",
    "terms and conditions": "Terms and conditions",
    "follow us": "Follow us"
  },
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the issue is not solved. I think const english = {} export default { english } has to be used.

Comment: Your usage of `export` is wrong. By doing `export default {  i18n }`, you are exporting new object with `i18n` property instead of exporting `i18n` instance. Just use `export default i18n`